# GetSupportFragmentManager() arguments returns null

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm implementing a Google Maps View wrapped inside a fragment. When I try to get the ID of the `mapsView`, I get a `nullpointer` exception from `getSupportFragmentManager()`, even though my class extends `FragmentActivity`. This is my code:

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTabChangeListener {

private TabHost mTabHost;
private Layouts l;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Util.setMainActivty(this);

    l = new Layouts();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        l.setMapsLayout();
}
}
```

My maps_layout fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Layouts class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.text.GetChars;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


public class Layouts extends FragmentActivity {

private MapView mMapView;

public void setMapsLayout() {

    MainActivity mainActivity = Util.getMainActivity();
    ViewGroup layoutContainer = (ViewGroup) mainActivity
            .findViewById(R.id.layoutContainer);
    layoutContainer.removeAllViews();


    View child1 = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity).inflate(
            R.layout.maps_layout, null);
    layoutContainer.addView(child1);


    GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


}


}
```

When I get to `getSupportFragmentManager()` its values are null. This is what I see: [image]

Does someone know what the problem is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't just create an instance of an `Activity` from another `Activity` and use it like that. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve but you will need to change your code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend **MainActivity** to FragmentActivity because google map support **FragmentActivity**.
Inside **MainActivity** activity class, you can implement **setMapsLayout()** the method.